# Tcl parsing for a command output exits without giving any output

Tags: tcl

I am trying to write a script that could parse the following output -

```
dev1# show stats all

20:01:02-180 (stats) ID=1a2b3c
Work Stats           -- Now -- -------- Overall --------
                T1    T2   Total      T5     T6    Total
container        3      3    0          3     3       3
operatioms         3      3    0          3     3       3
docker         3      3    0          3     3       3
tcl         3      3    0          3     3       3
app         3      3    0          3     3       3
external         1      4    0 
intra         2      6    0 
incoming locks         8      6    0 
outgoing locks         4      3    0 
race-condition times    10      20      23
threads/usage           45      56      70

Power       2.3          10
Consumption 20.3%       29%

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Separate Command
-----------------------------------------------------------------------



 dev1# show usage
    20:01:08-100
    OS:   48270 %
    Core:   4524 %
    User:   90 %
```

Unfortunately the device output is not formatted well.

While browsing through tcl blogs, I found one blog which had the following code -

```
 set input [dev1 run "show stats"]
    array unset output
    array set output {}

    foreach line [split $input "\n"] {
        if {[regexp {^([^:]+?)\s*:\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)?$} $line ]} {
            set key [string tolower $key 0 0]
            set output($key) $value
            if {[string length $units]} {
                set output(${key}Unit) $units

            }
        }
    }


    foreach {key value} [array get output] {
        puts [list $key $value]

    }
```

I am unable to get this to work. Although, the blog steps are followed. Can someone point out a few hints to solve this issue. I am new to the forum and would like to learn more.

Expected Output

```
 stats {

    {time 20:01:02-180}
    {id 1a2b3c}
    {cmd stats}
    {Now 
        {T1 {container 3} {operatioms 3} {docker 3} {tcl 3} {app 3} {extrenal 3} {intra 2} {incoming_locks 8} {outgoing_locks 4} {race-condition_times 10} {threads/usage 45}}
        {T2 {container 3} {operatioms 3} {docker 3} {tcl 3} {app 3} {extrenal 4} {intra 6} {incoming_locks 6} {outgoing_locks 3} {race-condition_times 20} {threads/usage 56}}
        {Total {container 3} {operatioms 3} {docker 3} {tcl 3} {app 3} {extrenal 4} {intra 6} {incoming_locks 0} {outgoing_locks 0} {race-condition_times 23} {threads/usage 70}}
    }
    {Overall 
        {T5 {container 3} {operatioms 3} {docker 3} {tcl 3} {app 3} }
        {T6 {container 3} {operatioms 3} {docker 3} {tcl 3} {app 3} }
        {Total {container 3} {operatioms 3} {docker 3} {tcl 3} {app 3} }
    }
    {Power {current 2.3} {total 10}}
    {Consumptiomn {current 20.3%} {total 29%}}

    }


    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------


    usage {

    {time 20:01:08-100}
    {OS 48270%}
    {Core 4524%}
    {User 90%}

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To better answer your question, please edit your question and specify what you are unable to get working. Is the code running, is it parsing some but not all of your output, is it parsing incorrectly, etc.

Comment: Thank you @buczek for your comments. I have updated the question.

Comment: You should look into your regex which does not parse all lines in the input. Add more regex for similar looking data and capture required values

Comment: You will have to write your own parser to get the output you're looking for. A single regex will not be able to retrieve everything like that (unless you make it absurdly long and hard to understand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that is a freaky output format.

It's not very hard to parse the text format, but producing the output format takes some doing.

Here are two commands that parse the output from the `stats` / `usage` commands and harvest data into dict structures:

```
proc parseStats txt {
    set data {}
    set keys1 {{Now T1} {Now T2} {Now Total} {Overall T5} {Overall T6} {Overall Total}}
    set keys2 {{Now T1} {Now T2} {Now Total}}
    foreach line [split [string trim $txt] \n] {
        switch -regexp -matchvar m $line {
            {^\s*(container)\M\s+(.*)} -
            {^\s*(operations)\M\s+(.*)} -
            {^\s*(docker)\M\s+(.*)} -
            {^\s*(tcl)\M\s+(.*)} -
            {^\s*(app)\M\s+(.*)} {
                lassign $m -> keystring values
                foreach key $keys1 val $values {
                    dict set data stats {*}$key $keystring $val
                }
            }
            {^\s*(external)\M\s+(.*)} -
            {^\s*(intra)\M\s+(.*)} -
            {^\s*(incoming locks)\M\s+(.*)} -
            {^\s*(outgoing locks)\M\s+(.*)} -
            {^\s*(race-condition times)\M\s+(.*)} -
            {^\s*(threads/usage)\M\s+(.*)} {
                lassign $m -> keystring values
                set keystring [string map {{ } _} $keystring]
                foreach key $keys2 val $values {
                    dict set data stats {*}$key $keystring $val
                }
            }
            {^\s*(Power)\M\s+(.*)} -
            {^\s*(Consumption)\M\s+(.*)} {
                lassign $m -> keystring values
                foreach lbl {current total} val $values {
                    dict set data stats $keystring $lbl $val
                }
            }
            ^\\d {
                dict set data stats time [lindex $line 0]
                dict set data stats cmd [string trim [lindex $line 1] ()]
                dict set data stats id [lindex [split [lindex $line 2] =] 1]
            }
        }
    }
    return $data
}

proc parseUsage txt {
    set data {}
    foreach line [split [string trim $txt] \n] {
        switch -regexp -matchvar m $line {
            {^\s*(OS)\M:\s+(.*)} -
            {^\s*(Core)\M:\s+(.*)} -
            {^\s*(User)\M:\s+(.*)} {
                lassign $m -> keystring values
                dict set data usage $keystring [join $values {}]
            }
            ^\\d {
                dict set data usage time $line
            }
        }
    }
    return $data
}
```

Assuming the output from the `stats` command is in the `statsText` variable, and the output from the `usage` command is in the `usageText` variable, you can construct these dictionary structures (note that the actual output is white-space-packed: I have added newlines and indents for readability).

```
% set stats [parseStats $statsText]
% set stats
stats {
    time 20:01:02-180
    cmd stats
    id 1a2b3c
    Now {
        T1 {container 3 docker 3 tcl 3 app 3 external 1 intra 2 incoming_locks 8 outgoing_locks 4 race-condition_times 10 threads/usage 45}
        T2 {container 3 docker 3 tcl 3 app 3 external 4 intra 6 incoming_locks 6 outgoing_locks 3 race-condition_times 20 threads/usage 56}
        Total {container 0 docker 0 tcl 0 app 0 external 0 intra 0 incoming_locks 0 outgoing_locks 0 race-condition_times 23 threads/usage 70}
   }
    Overall {
        T5 {container 3 docker 3 tcl 3 app 3}
        T6 {container 3 docker 3 tcl 3 app 3}
        Total {container 3 docker 3 tcl 3 app 3}
    }
    Power {current 2.3 total 10}
    Consumption {current 20.3% total 29%}
}

% set usage [parseUsage $usageText]
% set usage
usage {
    time 20:01:08-100
    OS 48270%
    Core 4524%
    User 90%
}
```

If you can, I urge you to use dictionaries like these instead of the output format in your question. It will be so much easier to process dictionaries.

If you must keep to the output format as shown, the following command converts the `dict` structure to a string that is functionally equivalent, if not white-space equivalent:

```
proc prettyPrintDict dict {
    dict for {k v} $dict {
        if {[llength $v] == 1} {
            append res "{$k $v}\n"
        } else {
            append r [prettyPrintDict $v]
            append res "$k {\n$r}\n"
            set r {}
        }
    }
    return $res
}

% puts [prettyPrintDict [parseStats $statsText]]
% puts [prettyPrintDict [parseUsage $usageText]]
```

Note that it relies on all values being words without whitespace.

Documentation: [append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm), [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm), [switch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/switch.htm)

Comment: Thanks @Peter ....One of the cases worked for me. For the other set I have different keys and some whites spaces. Is there a way to remove the white spaces only from part of the input?

Comment: @CentosNewbie: sure. The `switch` selectors are just regular expressions, with the grouping (the parentheses) telling what to extract using `lindex $m 1`. If you find that hard to do by yourself, please update your question with this new information, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @CentosNewbie: and now the answer is updated as well.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLewerin  .... Your tcl program worked like a charm. I will post an updated answer.